Из дублирующихся по товару строк оставить только одну
Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать запрос. Надо извлечь из таблицы invoice либо id этой накладной либо себестоимость из поля price_for_one.
select g.id, g.id, g.name
from goods_combos gc,
     goods g,
     invoice i,
     posinfo pi,
     stock_item si,
     warehouses w
where gc.combos_id = 10145
  and gc.goods_id = g.id
  and si.goods_id = g.id
  and pi.client_legal_informations_id = 12
  and w.pos_info_id = pi.id
  and si.warehouses_id = w.id
  and i.stock_item_id = si.id
  and i.archive = false
  and i.expense = false;

Проблема в том, что накладных (инвойсов) может быть десятки. Инвойс это запись о поступлении товара на склад. Из этих десятков накладных по одному товару надо оставить только одну - последнюю несписанную накладную.
Запрос в текущем виде возвращает все накладные по товару, пример:
288,10144,Тестовый товар 2
290,10147,Тестовый товар 3
291,10147,Тестовый товар 3

Видно, что тестовый товар 3 выведен в двух экземплярах. Как оставить только одну строку с тестовым товаром 3, которая соответствует последней несписанной накладной?

Да как обычно... ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и WHERE rn=1 во внешнем запросе.

А можно немного подробнее? Как использовать row_number и что такое CTE?

@Akina я до сих пор не сталкивался с row_number, оконными функциями и прочими вещами

WITH (Common Table Expressions)

Как Вы определяете последнюю несписанную накладную ?

Вот по этим условиям and i.archive = false
and i.expense = false;

У вас 3 строки с and i.archive = false and i.expense = false;. Как определяете последнюю из них?

Я сортировал order by i.id и делал limit 1, просто это сделано в другом запросе

Попробуйте row_number()over(order by i.id desc) rn и далее where rn=1, как писал Akina.

Спасибо, я справился
